# Socket.IO - socket.on not being ran

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sockets, socket.io

I have created a custom async emitter to have a `server -> client -> server` method.

However, it doesn't work as expected. It emits the event, but does not run the callback.

With Socket.IO debugging enabled, I can see that the `socket.io:socket` is logging that it is emitting the correct event.

Function code:

```
export async function asyncEmit<T>(
  region: string,
  socket: Server,
  event: string,
  data: {
    id: any;
    [k: string]: any;
  }
): Promise<{ result: T; error: boolean }> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    socket.to(region).emit(event, data);

    const cb = (res: { result: T; error: boolean }, ack: any) => {
      ack();
      if (res.error) {
        reject(res.result);
      }
      socket.off(`${data.id}-${event}`, cb);
      resolve(res);
    };

    socket.on(`${data.id}-${event}`, cb);
    setTimeout(() => {
      socket.off(event, cb);
      reject('Timed out.');
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

Some example code I'm using to run the function:

```
    const res = await asyncEmit<{ statistics: { members: number } }>(
      botRegion,
      socket,
      'statistics',
      { id: botId }
    );
```

The Socket.IO client does receive the emit and does return data correctly.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Edit, client side code is:

```js
        this.socketio.timeout(5000).emit(
          `${uuid}-statistics`,
          {
            result: { statistics: { members: guild.memberCount } },
            error: false,
          },
          (data: any, err: any) => {
            if (err) {
              this.logger.error(err);
            }
            if (data) {
              return;
            }
          }
        );
```

It does time out and log `socket.io-client:socket event with ack id 0 has timed out after 5000 ms +5s`

However on the server-side:

```
  socket.io:socket got packet {"type":2,"nsp":"/","id":0,"data":["......-statistics",{"result":{"statistics":{"members":35}},"error":false}]} +3s
  socket.io:socket emitting event ["......-statistics",{"result":{"statistics":{"members":35}},"error":false}] +0ms
  socket.io:socket attaching ack callback to event +0ms
  socket.io:socket dispatching an event ["......-statistics",{"result":{"statistics":{"members":35}},"error":false},null] +0ms
```

is logged. I believe this is some issue with my event handler code, however I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: Can you provide the receiving end's code ?

Comment: @Gabriel The async function is both the sending and receiving end; It sends the request, then waits for the client to send a request back (that's the socket.on handler), however it doesn't ever get triggered. With debug mode enabled, I can see that the server does get the data, but I don't think the EventHandler is being registered.

Comment: @Gabriel I updated my question to contain the client code and some more logs.

Comment: yes i'm aware, i believe you might have a few things mixed up regarding how they work, i'll answer in a moment and hopefully it'll clarify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rewriting my code to not use Socket.IO rooms, and to use a `Map<string, Socket>` and get the socket from there, so I can use Socket.IO callbacks.

This may not be the best way, but it's the only way I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks with Socket.io are different and are generally referred to as ***acknowledgement functions***

In order to implement callbacks, the sender would need to add the function to the **last** parameter of the `socket.emit()` call.

**Example:**

*Sender*

```
socket.emit("statistics", {test: "just a message"}, (response) => {
  console.log(response); // <-- should output "success"
});
```

*Receiver*

```
socket.on("statistics", (data, callback) => {
  console.log(data.test); // <-- should output "just a message"
  callback("success");//<-- this will return to the sender/emitter
});
```

*With timeout:*

```
socket.timeout(5000).emit("statistics", {test: "just a message"}, (err, response) => {
  if (err)
    // the event was not acknowledged by the receiver in the delay given
  else
    console.log(response); // <-- output is "success"
});
```

Do **note** how the first argument of the callback is the "*error*"

*In you example:

*Client-side:*

```
    this.socketio.timeout(5000).emit(
      `${uuid}-statistics`,
      {
        result: { statistics: { members: guild.memberCount } },
        error: false,
      },
      (err: any, data: any) => {
        if (err) {
          this.logger.error(err);
        }
        if (data) {
          console.log(data);//<-- this is where your callback resolves to
        }
      }
    );
```

*Server-side:*

```
const cb = (res: { result: T; error: boolean }, ack: any) => {
  //do whatever you want with res
  if (res.error) {
    console.log("Error:",res.result);
    ack("Errorfrom server");
  }

  socket.off(`${data.id}-${event}`, cb);
  console.log("Success:",res.result)

  ack("Success from server");//<--this callback will send back to the emitter
};
```

Edit your code according to this structure and give it a try.

Comment: That didn't work, Socket.IO still isn't emitting the event. I'm not sure if this is an issue with Node.js event emitters, or Socket.IO, or just my code. I tried moving the initial socket emitter to the bottom of the function to let the emitters register first, but that still did not work. Here's my current code: https://pastebin.com/sp3eKWyb

Comment: @jackmerrill probably how the code is structured, i am unable to currently test the code but try to debug by placing different logs. Remove `setTimeout` and empty the `cb` function and leave just one `console.log("This is a test")` inside `cb`.

Comment: good grief, I swear the socket.io docs makes no mention of that `.timeout` function nor that the callback of the listener is `(err, response)` https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/ and https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/emitting_events.html#From_server_to_client